# Displaying date/times in report

Tags: reporting, formula

I want to display the Date AND Time a document was created in a report.  By default, Salesforce reports only display the Date portion of the "Created Date" field.  Is there a way to get the Time portion of the field displayed in the report as well?

I'm fairly certain the records are sorted by Date and Time when that column is used to sort.  Do I have to create a second field to actually be able to see the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not a functionality offered by Salesforce. But there is a workaround. You will need to create a formula field that just pulls in the value of the Created or Last Modified field. That field will then show you both Date and Time in your reports.

Also, there is an idea under review on the community to make the Created and Last Modified show time in reports if you would like to vote for it [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000YwkLAAS).

Comment: @Jagular welcome! If this resolved your issue can you please mark it as the Best Answer so other users can quickly find the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

By default, you cannot see the time part of the date in your report.You have to create a custom field for this.Visit the below link which addresses this requirement by giving a workaround:

http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000176025

Above link suggests the workaround for your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

To display the time portion of created date, you can add a row level formula in the report, select text output, and use a formula:

TEXT(TIMEVALUE(Created_Date))

[image: Example of formula input]

Then add it to the report:

[image: Example report with time portion]

Answer (score 0):

A slight variation on @Rodrigo's idea, choose 'Date/Time' as the Output Type of the Row Level Formula and use the DateTimeValue function and you can show the date and time in one column.

Note that at the time of writing, each report supports 1 row-level formula.

[image]

[image]